# How to implement deserialization of ros2 messages

Tags: c++, ros2

After I serialized the ros2 message and extracted the buffer data, When I deserialize as follows，It has the following problem：terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rcpputils::IllegalStateException'
what():  Wrongly initialized. Serialized message has a size of zero.
[ros2run]: Aborted

```cpp
void callbackCloudResponseMessage(const planning_interface::msg::Cloud & msg) {

    /* serialize */
    rclcpp::Serialization<planning_interface::msg::Cloud> cloudSerializer;
    rclcpp::SerializedMessage serialized_msg;
    cloudSerializer.serialize_message(&msg, &serialized_msg);

    uint8_t* serialized_data = serialized_msg.get_rcl_serialized_message().buffer;
    size_t serialized_size = serialized_msg.size();
    
    static uint8_t buf_test[FRAME_LENGTH_MAX+1];
    uint8_t *pmsg_test = buf_test + DATA_PAYLOAD;
    memcpy(pmsg_test, serialized_data, serialized_size);

    /* deserialize */
    planning_interface::msg::Cloud test_msg;
    rclcpp::SerializedMessage serialize_test_msg(serialized_size);
    memcpy(new_msg.get_rcl_serialized_message().buffer, pmsg_test, serialized_size);
    cloudSerializer.deserialize_message(&new_msg, &test_msg);

}
```

I tried the above method and expected to be able to deserialize

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that `serialize_test_msg` is just an unfinished rename of `new_msg` or vice versa which you did *after* run, otherwise your example wouldn't compile in the first place)

The problem is that `new_msg` is zero size when you call `deserialize_message` because `rclcpp::SerializedMessage` [constructor](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1SerializedMessage.html#af9d22194b1cc1c216cd743c52d33dcc8) you use takes `size_t` as *capacity*, not *size*, of the created buffer. It allocates memory (to which you then successfully `memcpy`) and sets `buffer`, `buffer_capacity` and `allocator` fields of the [underlying struct](https://docs.ros2.org/dashing/api/rcutils/structrcutils__uint8__array__t.html#a6624cb9bca26efb087b1da9807d06e38), but `buffer_length` field remains zero and the buffer is initially empty. `memcpy` only writes data to the buffer (within capacity, so no problems here), but `buffer_length` remains untouched and so `new_msg.get_rcl_serialized_message()` is in logically invalid state which can't be properly interpreted by `deserialize_message`. So, before doing deserializing, you should fix this by manually setting `buffer_length` (this doesn't require reallocation since it's, trivially, within capacity to which it is equal):

```
// ...
memcpy(new_msg.get_rcl_serialized_message().buffer, pmsg_test, serialized_size);
new_msg.get_rcl_serialized_message().buffer_length = serialized_size;
cloudSerializer.deserialize_message(&new_msg, &test_msg);
```